# Why does my app keep crashing?

Tags: android, facebook

I've been implementing Facebook into my app but for some reason it keeps crashing. I cannot see any errors or reasons for it crashing. The logcat for the app is too large to include here, so heres a link to it: http://pastebin.com/b8Zbyu0v

Heres the source code im using:

```
package com.myCompany.myProject;

import com.facebook.LoggingBehavior;
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.Settings;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;

import android.R.string;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String URL_PREFIX_FRIENDS = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=";

    private TextView textInstructionsOrLink;
    private Button buttonLoginLogout;
    private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        buttonLoginLogout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonLoginLogout);
        textInstructionsOrLink = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.instructionsOrLink);

        Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session == null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, statusCallback, savedInstanceState);
            }
            if (session == null) {
                session = new Session(this);
            }
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
                session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
            }
        }

        updateView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(statusCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Session.getActiveSession().removeCallback(statusCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        Session.saveSession(session, outState);
    }

    private void updateView() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            textInstructionsOrLink.setText(URL_PREFIX_FRIENDS + session.getAccessToken());
            buttonLoginLogout.setText("Logout");
            buttonLoginLogout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) { onClickLogout(); }
            });
        } else {
            textInstructionsOrLink.setText("Please login by clicking the button");
            buttonLoginLogout.setText("Login");
            buttonLoginLogout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) { onClickLogin(); }
            });
        }
    }

    private void onClickLogin() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
        } else {
            Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
        }
    }

    private void onClickLogout() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (!session.isClosed()) {
            session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            updateView();
        }
    }

}
```

And heres the XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/authButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/instructionsOrLink"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Does anyone know why it might be crashing??

Comment: Log says that your `applicationId` cannot be null. Check in `onCreate()` .MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45) line 45

Comment: But i dont see a duplication anywhere??? can anyone else see one?

Comment: applicationId cannot be null this is cause of duplication

Answer (score 0):

you must define your `applicationId` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` like this:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
           android:value="@string/app_id"/>
```

under `<application android:label="@string/app_name"....` tag

where `app_id` is a string within your `strings.xml`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've checked the manifest and this line already exists. Is there anything else you can think of?